# 14.04 - Does trash empty automatically after awhile?

Tags: 14.04, trash

I deleted 100gb of files off my desktop the other day and it still seems to be taking up HDD space.

Comment: It doesn't, but you can make it :)

Comment: Set up a cronjob with bleachbit's command line options, and it'll do everything for you periodically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default it doesn't. You can empty it manually by right-clicking on the trash icon in the launcher and then clicking "Empty Trash ...".

If you want it to do this automatically, open a terminal and enter this command:

```
sudo apt-get install trash-cli
```

Then open "Startup Applications" from the dash. Click "Add" and enter `trash-empty 5` as command, choose some name you like. This will delete all files which are longer than 5 days in your trash every time you log in to your computer.

Comment: Wow... I didn't even notice there was a trash icon on the launcher. I was using  rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/

Comment: In recent Ubuntu distribution, you don't need third party clients anymore, you can use `gio trash` and to empty the trash, the command is `gio trash --empty`.

Comment: BUT does that delete ALL trash or just older trash?

Comment: @anthony Look at [this example](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/trash-empty.1.html). It only deletes old files.

Comment: I was talking about gio trash,  not trash-cli commands!

Comment: WARNING: trash-cli has some serious problems, (symlinks, handling other filesystems, and alternative locations).  It also does not appear to be maintained.   See its git 'issues', and you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

> I deleted 100gb of files off my desktop the other day and it still seems to be taking up HDD space.

Nothing to add to what has been said already, but this is expected because files moved to the trash are not deleted, but just moved to `~/.local/share/Trash`. Only by emptying the trash you'll regain your free space

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not. The Trash is just a regular folder on your drive (`/home/YOURUSERNAME/.local/share/Trash/`). "Deleted" files are instead of really deleting just moved to its subfolder `files/` and another file in the subfolder `info/` is created to provide additional information about it (date of deletion, origin,...). Therefore a trashed file still occupies space on the disk.

The Trash (of which each user account has its own) usually never gets emptied automatically. At least not depending on the time, maybe if it grows too large, but I don't think so. You have to do it manually (right-clicking on its Unity launcher icon or inside your file manager, e.g. Nautilus) or schedule a job to perform it automatically, but I would recommend you to take the old-school way and do it by hand. :)